# Cannot examine breakpoints in PhpStorm with Xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a simple Apache + PHP 7.1 web server running locally.

I've got Xdebug helper installed in Chrome, and I click "*Debug*" in that.

I've got Xdebug 2.9.2 extension running successfully in PHP, with correct output from `phpinfo();`

When I run "validate" in PhpStorm I get green ticks for all but the last item, "*Debug protocol '' is not supported*", which has a yellow triangle.

I set a debug point in my code, and hit the green bug in the toolbar to begin a debugging session, and the only thing that's output in the Debugger "Variables" pane in PhpStorm is "*Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '13508'*" (this number changes every time).

Within php.ini I have set `xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"`, and I've mirrored this in my Chrome Xdebug Helper.

I am not running Zend Debug.

I would really like to be able to debug properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow the PHP Storm help and tutorial.

Comment: *"When I run "validate" in PhpStorm I get green ticks for all but the last item, "Debug protocol '' is not supported", which has a yellow triangle."* You can ignore this moment -- current Xdebug version does not support that option any more.

Comment: I suggest 1) double checking `phpinfo()` output, Xdebug section (captured via the same way as you will be debugging -- a CLI or web browser) to confirm that Xdebug is enabled. List that here (whole Xdebug section). 2) Enable Xdebug log and see what it has to say about it (where it tries to connect to and if it tries at all). 3) It's possible that you need to provide path mappings (e.g. if you have symbolic links in a path).

Comment: 4) Also check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html in particular

Comment: Hi @LazyOne,
https://imgur.com/a/rNM6yKL
This is my full XDebug. I'm going to be debugging via web browser.
I don't know how to provide path mappings. My web server is using symbolic links but in PHPStorm I'm using the full direct path.
I'm going to check the XDebug log now.

Comment: XDebug log is pretty unhelpful: https://pastebin.com/CKPTwDh1
*[2097] W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).*

Comment: I disabled all symlinks but the same result exists. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: @StiofanMac Accordingly to your Xdebug log, you already have some service running on TCP 9000 port ... and that does not look like it's PhpStorm. Most likely it's **php-fpm** (it also uses the same port by default). You can check that with `netstat` or alike (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` if you are on Mac). **Solution** -- change Xdebug port in both php.ini and PhpStorm to be some another number -- e.g. `9001` or so; restart web server and IDE.

Comment: @LazyOne, you're 100% correct. The problem was port 9000 being used by PHP-FPM. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to your [Xdebug log](https://pastebin.com/CKPTwDh1), you already have some service running on TCP 9000 port and that does not seem to be PhpStorm. Most likely it's **php-fpm** (it also uses the same port by default).

You can check that with `netstat` or alike (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` if you are on Mac) -- it can show associated process ID (or even process name straight away).

**Solution:** change Xdebug port in both php.ini and PhpStorm to be some another number -- e.g. `9001` or so; restart web server once done.

Comment: Thank you, this was correct.
Very much appreciated, not so @LazyOne :)